# Rails 6 change params to hash of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an app where the user has to fill out a survey. I need to store user's answers in inside `TestResult` model which have only one field `answers:string`

With current implementation I'm getting params from the form as:

```
params => {
  {
    "question_#{id}": "some answer 1",
    "question_#{id}": "some answer 12345",
  }
}
```

Which I want to change to the below structure:

```
# expected hash params
params => {
  {
    question: 'first question',
    answer: 'some answer 1'
  },
  {
    question: 'second question',
    answer: 'some answer 123431'
  }
}
```

What should I change (probably in a view) to get this hash?

`new.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for :test_results, url: test_results_path  do |f| %>
  <% @randomize_questions.map do |q| %>
    <%= q[:question] %>
    <%= f.input "question_#{q[:id]}", collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
class TestResultsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :fetch_random_questions, only: [:new, :create]

  def new
    @test_result = TestResult.new
  end

  def create
    @test_result = TestResult.new(
      answer: test_result_params,
    )

    @test_result.save
    redirect_to dummy_path
    end
  end

  private

  def test_result_params
    params.require(:test_results).permit!
  end

  def fetch_random_questions
    TestQuestion.where(published: true).order('RANDOM()')

    @randomize_questions = test_questions.map do |obj|
      {
        id: obj.id,
        question: obj.question,
        answers: [obj.correct_answer, obj.other_answer1, obj.other_answer2, obj.other_answer3],
      }
    end
  end
end
```

TestResult model

class TestResult < ApplicationRecord
serialize :answer, Hash
serialize :answer, String
validates :answer, presence: true
end

Comment: How does TestResult look? Is it a combination of question_id and answer_id or texts?

Comment: @Joel_Blum Question updated, it's just a one table field `answer` where I want to store all answers as a hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The params get his structure from the input names.

So you could add an hidden field for question, and then specify a name for both of your fields.

```
<%= simple_form_for :test_results, url: test_results_path  do |f| %>
  <% @randomize_questions.map do |q| %>
    <%= q[:question] %>
    <%= f.input "question_#{q[:id]}", as: :hidden, input_html: { name: "test_results[#{q[:id]}][question]", value: q[:question] }  %>
    <%= f.input "question_#{q[:id]}", collection: q[:answers], as: :radio_buttons, input_html: { name: "test_results[#{q[:id]}][answer]" } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Params should looks like this:

```
params => {
  test_result: {
    1 => {
      question: "...",
      answer: "..."
    },
    2 => {
      question: "...",
      answer: "..."
    }
  }
}
```

**Not tested.** Could you tell if that's works for you?

Comment: With your code I'm getting an error: `ActionController::ParameterMissing in TestResultsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: test_results`

Comment: Should be the input names. I missed the 's'.  => `name: 'test_results[#{q[:id]}][question]` and `name: 'test_results[#{q[:id]}][answer]'`

Comment: Well... that's not what I expected, seems like each new test_result is an ActionController::Parameters object inside of hash. Check it out: `{"1"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"answer"=>"Est voluptate quo.", "question"=>"question of category1"} permitted: true>, "2"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"answer"=>"", "question"=>"question of category2"} permitted: true>, "8"=>#<ActionController::Parameters {"answer"=>"", "question"=>"question of category3"} permitted: true>, (...) `

Comment: @mr_muscle `ActionController::Parameters` instances implement the `to_hash` method, so you should be able to pass them where a hash is expected and they will be converted into a hash automatically. If you pass it to one of you own methods make sure to call `to_hash` if you expect a hash and the provided argument is not a hash. Alternatively you can convert them using `.transform_values(&:to_h)`

Comment: Ok, it works! but I still have no idea where the question id comes from. I mean when I've got params => test_result: { 1 => { question: "...", answer: "..." }, 23 => { ... }, }` the integers (1 and 23) are corresponding to the `q[:id]` but how come?

Comment: It comes from `@randomize_questions` you defined in your controller. It looks like it is a collection of `questions` structured as hash with keys: 'id', 'question' and 'answers'.